# Understanding simple weighted average

Tags: python, weighted-mean, weighted-data, pandas

The basic question is: Why is the weighted average of the column that is the "weight" different than it's mean?

I'll use an example below. It makes sense to me why To_Weight looks significantly different when you use the Weighted column. But intuitively I can't seem to make sense of why the Weighted Average of the thing we're using as a weight changes so different from it's average?

```
In [68]: d = {1: {'Weighted': 1200, 'To_Weight': 20}, 2: {'Weighted': 1500, 'To_Weight': 10}, 3:{'Weighted': 12000, 'To_Weight': 10}, 4: {'Weighted': 12000, 'To_Weight': 5}}

In [69]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
   Weighted  To_Weight
1      1200         20
2      1500         10
3     12000         10
4     12000          5

In [71]: df.Weighted.mean()
Out[71]: 6675.0

In [72]: df.To_Weight.mean()
Out[72]: 11.25

In [73]: df['WA_TO'] = df['To_Weight'] * df['Weighted'] / df['Weighted'].sum()

In [75]: df['WA_TO'].sum()
Out[75]: 8.202247191011237

In [76]: df['WA_Weighted'] = df['Weighted'] * df['Weighted'] / df['Weighted'].sum()

In [77]: df['WA_Weighted'].sum()
Out[77]: 10924.719101123595
```

Comment: What precisely is your question?  What number are you surprised is so different from what other number?

Comment: Why is WA_Weighted 10.9k and the Weighted.mean() is 6,675 when we're "weighting" by itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you weighted the weights by themselves?

Then the same concept applies; imagine the numbers from the "Weighted" column as the ones in the "To_Weight" column. You said yourself that you expected the weighted average of To_Weight to be different from the unweighted average of To_Weight. The same can apply for any set of numbers you put into the "To_Weight" column, even the ones from the "Weighted" column.

Generally the weighted average (ie. weights are not 1) of any set of numbers can very different from the unweighted average, even if the set of numbers is the weights themselves.

Comment: So I should make sure I avoid this weighting by itself behavior, right?

Comment: Usually there isn't any reason to weight observations by themselves. The weights are usually calculated based on how many units in the population are represented by each observation.

Comment: For example, if there population has 50% males and 50% females, but in your sample you have 75% males and 25% females, then your observations should be reweighted so that the female observations have equal impact as the males.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try and explain this difference with a simple example.  Suppose I wanted to take the weight average of 2 and 4, with weight 2 and 4, respectively.  As you know from your computations that would be equal to:

$$
\frac{2\cdot2 + 4\cdot4}{2 + 4} = \frac{2+2+4+4+4+4}{6}.
$$

A weighted average of $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ by itself is not necessarily equal to an unweighted average.  A weighted average of $\mathbf{x}$ *by all ones* is equal to an unweighted average.